# Xcode iOS : How to parse this JSON?

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I am trying to parse this JSON string. However I keep having problem at the NSArray.

```
var tContacts: [String] = []


if let jsonData = data {
                //let jsonObj = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
                let jsonObj = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
                print(jsonObj)



                let rescode = jsonObj["respond"] as! String?
               altogether")


                self.tContacts = jsonObj["mylist"] as! Array  **(ERROR HERE)**
................
...........
......
}
```

Error:
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x107b25288) to 'NSString' (0x107130c60).

```
["list_id": 1, "respond": success, "mylist": <__NSArrayI 0x618000231b60>(
{
    email = "porkman@live.com";
    name = John;
    status = active;
},
{
    email = "gorillaunderwear@gmail.com";
    name = Gregh;
    status = active;
}
)
]
```

Comment: how did you defined the self.tContacts ?

Comment: like this: var tContacts: [String] = []

Comment: `jsonObj["mylist"]` is a `[[String:Any]]` (Array of Dictionaries) which is not the same as `[String]` (Array of Strings) as is defined `tContacts`.

Comment: @OneNation try   `var tContacts: NSDictionary !`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tContacts is an array of String but `jsonObj["mylist"]` returns Array of Dictionaries. You can declare your tContacts as array of Any objects

```
var tContacts: [Any] = []  or
var tContacts:[[String:Any]] = [[:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace **var tContacts: [String] = []** in to `var tContacts: [[String:AnyObject]] = [[String:AnyObject]]()`

Hope this will help you...